# System Verilog : Concatenate 0's n times when n is unknown at compile time

Tags: concatenation, system-verilog

> I am trying to concatenate 0 "n" times but "n 'is unknown to me at compile time.
>
> "n" is calculated using some calculation which depends on random input(temp_i).

```
    string s=temp_i;
      int n,d_zero;
   int i=0; 
    int l=s.len()*8;//l=24
     int k=447-l;
     int T=0;
     if(k<0)
       k=512+k;
     
     do
     begin
      d[i]=l%2;
      i++;             
     end while(l>0);
     
     T=l+1+k+d.size();
     n=T/512;
```

> This "n" numbers of zero has to be concatenated with the input. Something like:

```
    temp_out={temp_i,n'{1'b0}}
```

But I am getting a syntax error concatenating like this.

Can someone please help me out with this? Is there any other way I can get this done ?

---

Comment: What is the type of temp_i and temp_out. Are they strings?

Comment: How about using the shift operator;  `temp_out = temp_in << n`?

Comment: @Greg This method is far simpler and straight forward than the one I tried. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by just declaring "n"  as localparam.

```
    localparam n;
```

and temp_out as

```
  temp_out={temp_i,{n{1'b0}}};
```